# Run bat files in folder wby parent bat file

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory

I would like to know how i can create a bat file that will execute all other bat files found in a specific directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way

```
for %%f in (c:\xxx\*.bat) do (
   call %%f
)
```

(To run it from the same folder you would need to exclude the executing file)

```
if %%f neq %0.bat (
    call %%f
)
```

Answer (score 0):

thats pretty straight forward

hope this helps
just navigate to your directory and then just write the name of your batch file

Abc.bat

```
cd dirwhereBATCHfileLies
batch1
batch2
batch3
```

Comment: oops, misread the question. missed the word `all` in the question. in case want to execute all the batches. Alex has given it right. my method is to execute selected batches from a directory.  :-)